# gsoap and qt convert variables memory handle

Tags: c++, qt, gsoap

i use this code to convert Qstring to gsoap standard wchar_t;

```
wchar_t *MGsoapQtChanger::toGsoap(QString str)
{
    s= new wchar_t[str.size()+1];
    int i=str.toWCharArray(s);
    s[i]='\0';
    return s;
}
```

and it work good for me. but the problem is here that i do new wchar_t and i dont delete it because i need to send it to my client. how can i delete this variable after i send it for my client.

```
///crunable.cpp///

#include "crunable.h"

CRunable::CRunable()
{

}

void CRunable::run()
{
c->serve();
c->destroy();
delete c;
}

void CRunable::setParam(calcService *c)
{
    this->c=c;
}

///convert function///////

wchar_t *MGsoapQtChanger::toGsoap(QString str)
{
    s= new wchar_t[str.size()+1];
    int i=str.toWCharArray(s);
    s[i]='\0';
    return s;
}

///listen function//

void MListen::listen()
{
    memcService calcS(SOAP_XML_INDENT);
    if (calcS.run(80) != SOAP_OK)
    calcS.soap_stream_fault(std::cerr);
    calcS.destroy(); // same as:soap_destroy(calc.soap);
    soap_end(calc.soap);
}

int memcService::uppercase(wchar_t *str, wchar_t *&r){
    MGsoapQtChanger mg;
    QString s= mg.toQt(str);
    s=s.toUpper();
    r=mg.toGsoap(s);
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

Comment: Can't you keep a copy of the pointer and delete it later, e.g. in destructor?

Comment: destructor of what class? service class is created by gsoap and i dont want to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you are tempted to write `new T[]`, write `vector<T>` instead. I haven't found a legit case where I had to use the array new form in several years of C++ use, except for implementing low-level containers like `vector` and `string`.

However, in this special case, you could also consider `wstring`:

```
wstring res;
res.resize(str.size());
int i = str.toWCharArray(&s[0]);
res.resize(i);
return res;
```

Comment: wchar_t is an standard gsoap variable for send and resive utf characters . and i can not use wstring i think.

Comment: `std::wstring` is `std::basic_string<wchar_t>`, I'm pretty sure you can use it.